# CLLocation Manager giving incorrect location sometime

Tags: ios, core-location

I am using core location API for iOS (CLLocation manager) and its sometimes giving me wrong location like if I am in U.S it gives me latitude and longitude of Spain. Searched stack over flow for the same but couldn't get a relevant answer for my query. Being novice to the use maps and locations I am a bit confused. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is this only on simulator or on a physical device?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are using a physical device and not the simulator to test this, and you did not select the option to simulate location in xcode. Sometimes CLLocation manager can return for example an old cached location, so perhaps that is what happened to you. Before you do anything with received CLLocation object I recommend checking its horizontalAccuracy and timestamp properties.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    guard let lastLocation = locations.last, lastLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 1000, abs(lastLocation.timestamp.timeIntervalSinceNow) < 60 else {
        // location not accurate or to old (cached previously) so do not do anything
        return
    }
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Apple use wifi devices around for location detection. So on "cold" start gps chip needs some time to start and find satellites, and during that time device use location based on router's mac addresses around. If your (or your neighbor's) router ever been in Spain, than that's the reason - Apple database of mac addresses refresh very slowly, it could take 1-3 months for that.